# Windows Server 2003 Services are stopping every 15-20 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, network-share

We have a new server installation that has a handful of services failing over and over.  They include, but are not limited to, the following:

- Computer Browser
- Server
- Help and Support
- HID Input Service
- Cryptographic Services
- Task Scheduler
- Secondary Logon

There are probably half a dozen other services that I believe are failing as well.  The most crucial are obviously the first two, as we need them working for all our shares to function.  I have set all services to restart immediately when they fail, but the problem is that the event log is not showing anything when the services fail.  It's only throwing up errors from other apps trying to access shares, so I'm not able to really see what's going on with this.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I have not been able to run sfc yet, as I am only able to access the server remotely.  However, in the meantime, this server is having more severe problems, it seems.  It has, three times in less than a week, frozen up completely, such that it is not even possible to log-in, locally or remotely.  I'm seeing this error a lot in the event log now: "UPS Communication Loss: Occurred on 27-Apr-2011 3:23:00 AM at device "[%IPaddress%]%servername%/UPS02"."  The source is Liebert Multilink and the event ID is 1.

Comment: re: update, Do you have an ability to update BIOS, chipset, firmware's on the server from the manufacturer's site?

Answer (score 0):

Revert the changes done to the restart option, clear the log and reboot the server. Submit eventid for the errors which will happen when the services will be restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I may have been unclear in my original question.  The server had been having this issue for about a week before it was brought to me.  There is a long error log from the apps trying to use shared folders, but there are no reports of errors from the services failing.  This was happening before any changes were made.  I'm not sure they would be able to restart the server in the middle of a business day either, unfortunately.  How would rebooting differ from just turning off the automatic service restarts?

Comment: Are you saying that services fails without writing anything to the event log? It's extremely unusual.

Comment: Correct, the Application log was not showing any errors for services failing or stopping.  It was only giving errors when other applications tried to access the unavailable shares.  That has been the biggest reason why I've been stumped so far.

Comment: Did you try updating the system with the latest updates & SP?

Comment: Yes, it's up-to-date, SP2 Build 3790.

Comment: Try running `sfc` on the system

Comment: I ran sfc and it came up with nothing.  I ended up getting this server duct taped together by setting all services to immediately restart, but never came up with anything permanent.  It was also crashing randomly, but setting weekly reboots seems to have minimized that issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [Hotfix 932762](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932762).  This could be the cause of your problem.

As the Hotfix describes, this can occur if a third party server becomes the master browser.

Comment: That looks pretty good.  I had seen this before, but since I wasn't seeing any svchost.exe errors in the event log, and have been able to restart services okay, I wasn't sure if it applied.  I will give this a try.

Comment: After applying the hotfix and restarting the server, the services were okay, but then failed again after about 40 minutes.  The only event showing up in the log is:

Comment: The EventSystem sub system is suppressing duplicate event log entries for a duration of 0 seconds.  The suppression timeout can be controlled by a REG_DWORD value named SuppressDuplicateDuration under the following registry key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\EventSystem\EventLog.

Comment: There are no warning or informational messages in any logs around the time the service fails?

Comment: Yes, that's what's so frustrating about this.  The system is giving me nothing to look at for clues.